# Finding string slices in an array of string slices

Tags: rust

I have a large array of statically allocated string slices, defined like so:

```
const ARR: [&'static str; 50] = [...];
```

I'm then iterating through the array in what I assume is a normal manner (I'm new to Rust):

```
for el in ARR.iter() {
    if el == target {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when I try to use `eq()`:

```
error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<str>` is not implemented for the type `&str`
```

Is there something in the standard library to compare string slices, or do I have to just iterate through and compare characters myself? And, for that matter, is there a better way to search for an element in an array than what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you write `el.eq(target)` rather than `el == target`?

Comment: @huon-dbaupp: The string I'm searching for in the array

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I've been writing a lot of Java code lately; bad habit.

Comment: @DavidPearson: have you tried running it after changing it to `==`? I think it should work now, for `.eq()` wanted a `&T` where `T` is the type being compared to, (and `target` was presumably `&str`, and `&str` is not comparable to `str`) but `==` takes a reference itself and should have resolved the issue.

Comment: @DavidPearson, I mean, what type is it specifically? (Was unclear initially, sorry.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I did make that change, but I'm still seeing the same error
@huon-dbaupp target is of type `&str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could write your example:

```rust
const FRUITS: [&'static str; 3] = ["apple", "banana", "coconut"];

fn is_available(desired: &str) -> bool {
    for &el in FRUITS.iter() {
        // let () = el; // PROTIP
        if el == desired {
          return true;
        }
    }

    false
}
```

See where I assigned `el` to `()`? That's a little trick to see what the type of a variable is at some point. If you uncomment that, you'll get an error like:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&&str`,
    found `()`
```

This lets you know what the types are. The second part is to look at the implementations of `PartialEq` for `str`, the important one being:

```
impl PartialEq<str> for str
```

So we bind `el` with a pattern that will automatically dereference it once for us. Then the comparison can take place, as we have a balanced amount of dereferencing to do:

```
for &el in FRUITS.iter() {
//  ^~~ Here
```

But really, I'd write it like this:

```rust
static FRUITS: [&'static str; 3] = ["apple", "banana", "coconut"];

fn main() {
    let desired = "apple";
    let to_eat = FRUITS.iter().find(|&&f| f == desired);
    println!("{:?}", to_eat);

    let desired = "durian";
    let to_eat = FRUITS.iter().find(|&&f| f == desired);
    println!("{:?}", to_eat);
}
```

`static` creates an actual shared place in memory for the variable. `const` acts more like a C `#define` - the value is inserted everywhere it is used. Since `find` returns the item, we need it to have some storage that lasts for longer than the one expression.

[`IteratorExt::find`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.find) also abstracts the work of finding a matching value (for some condition), and returns an [`Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) denoting success / failure.